# App crashes on showing ProgressDialog in non-activity

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, progressdialog, android-context

From my MainActivty I'm trying to call a method of non-activity class with the following line:

```
Context context;
context = getApplicationContext();
mClient.start(context);
```

In non activity-class:

```
 public void start(Context context) {

    final ProgressDialog startDialog;
    startDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    startDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    startDialog.setCancelable(false);
    startDialog.show();

    mHandler.post(new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d(TAG,"Connecting to the server...");

            try {
                connect();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }               

      startDialog.dismiss();

 }
```

The app crashes with the following message:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Where's the mistake?

Comment: no it is not possible. It it was a non-activity class you would have get a compile time error

Comment: it should be possible if you pass a context as argument to the non activity class

Comment: of course it is possible, but `new ProgressDialog(this);` implies differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass context parameter in `ProgressDialog`,So Change

```
startDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

to

```
startDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

And in your mainActivity change

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```

to

```
context = MainActivty.this;
```

Comment: This seems to work. But I don't understand why context = getApplicationContext(); doesn't work. If I call it from MainActivity.this, it should save 'MainActivity.this' in context variable...

Comment: @andreasperelli see this [When to call activity context OR application context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

Answer (score 1):

try to change this in your non-activity class `.start(....)` method

```
  startDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

instead of

```
  startDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

also you need to change in your `mainActivity`

```
  context = getApplicationContext();
```

to

```
 context = MainActivity.this;;
```

You need to pass context to create `Progress Dialog` in non-activity class

Answer (score 0):

```
startDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
```